# Orden de los Campos en XML WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soapui

Rengo un caso con un WCF que no me permite recibir los datos correctamente al consumirlo desde una herramienta externa, ejemplo (SOAP UI), tengo el siguiente `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Ticket
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TableNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Este es mi Contrato:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]        
    Task<int> ExecuteATransfer(Ticket TransferRequest);
```

Al consumir el WCF desde el SOAP UI esta es la estructura inicial:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wcf="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/wcfPCBApp">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:ExecuteATransfer>
         <tem:TransferRequest>

            <wcf:ServerId>100</wcf:ServerId>
            <wcf:TableNumber>205</wcf:TableNumber>
            <wcf:TicketId>5894</wcf:TicketId>
            <wcf:Timestamp>2016-08-25</wcf:Timestamp>
         </tem:TransferRequest>
      </tem:ExecuteATransfer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Pero si se invierte uno de los campos en la estructura XML desde el SopaUI como por ejemplo el DataMenber ServerId con TableNumber:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar el consumo o peticion el campo ServerId llega vacio aunque en el SOAP UI se le asigne un Valor especifico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se logra apreciar que el valor llega en 0 cuando debería ser 100.

Answer (score 2):

En al deserializacion WCF toma en cuanta el orden de las propiedades

[WCF Data Member Order](http://kblite.blogspot.com.ar/2014/02/wcf-data-member-order.html)

Es mas observaras que puedes cambiarlo

```
[DataContract]
public class Ticket
{
    [DataMember(Order=2)]
    public int TicketId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public int TableNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public int ServerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=3)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

la idea es que las propiedades mapeen en el orden del xml serializado a soap

[Orden de los miembros de datos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Que pasaria en el caso de que se desconozca el orden en que cualquier cliente que consuma el servicio lo vaya a enviar.? Es decir el WCF estara libre, cualquier cliente que lo consuma podra enviarlos en el orden que el disponga. MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Pasaria lo que comentas en el problema que planteas los datos no van a deserializarse correctamente. Entiendo que el tema esta relacionado como soap define el xml que envia al servicio, el cliente puede enviarlo en el orden que quiera pero no el va a funcionar ya que habra propiedades que no asigne el valor correctamente. Quizas si quieres algo mas desestructurado debas evaluar crear servicio REST ya que el model binding de este es mas permisivo y soporta json